# JavaScript validating if a upload file is what its extension is

Tags: javascript, validation, upload

I've come across a situation where I'm attempting to validate that only certain types of files are allowed to be uploaded.

The method I was working on is to check the header of the 64b encode to see if its a match to the accepted files.

```
  dataHeader = (b64FileString.split(';'))[0]
  imgRegex = /data:image\/((jpeg)|(jpg)|(gif)|(exif)|(tiff)|(bmp)|(png)|(bpg))?$/gmi;
```

If I attempt to upload an image file `image.png` the header looks like this `"data:image/png"` and the regex works.

This method works, but only to a certain degree.

Starting this process my assumption is that the header is based on the actual file format, but this is not true. The header is actually just based on the file extension.

If I have the following in windows `program.exe`,

the header looks like this `"data:application/x-msdownload"`

The regex does not match and the file is not accepted.

If a user changes the extension of `program.exe` to `program.png`,

The header now is `"data:image/png"` and the regex accepts.

What can be done to validate that an image file is actually an image file, and not a relabeled something else?

Comment: Likely find a library that will do this for you

Comment: [Here's an article](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/determine-an-images-type-using-the-javascript-filereader.html) that talks about using "magic numbers" to determine a file type (basically checking the file headers).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you desire, I suspect you will have to analyse the file data itself, and compare the byte signatures ([magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files)) with types that you want to allow. If your server streams the bytes in, you should be able to check, and cancel early if an invalid signature is found. For example, all `png` files begin with:

```
137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10 
  or in hex
89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A
```

If you are using say *node* as your backend, you could use a lib like [`file-type`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type) to achieve this fairly easily.